# Booting a different GRUB entry the next time only

Tags: linux, boot, grub

Is there a way to boot another OS or a different kernel the next time the machine reboots, but on the reboot after that go back to the original default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo "savedefault --default=2 --once" | grub --batch
```

where 2 means to boot the 3rd menu entry in `grub.conf`.

Change 2 to the appropriate menu entry number you want to boot next time.